# How to get result from corfirmation dialog

Tags: python, dialog, pyqt, pyqt4

I have problem with the results of my pop-up window. Below I have shown part of my code to understand the problem.

It's a kind of pop-up window where the user makes some choice in the GUI. After this it should show a window where there will be the question "Are you sure?", and two buttons "Yes" and "No".

The problem is that when I test the code below (before and after the  `msg.show()`), I have the same value set as `False`.

Why doesnt it work like this:

- Before function -> `False`
- Show my window and wait to click the button
- If I clicked button "Yes", then give `True`, else `False`

How I can handle this properly? Is there another approach?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from Message import Ui_Message
import sys

class MessageBox(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.msg = Ui_Message()
        self.msg.setupUi(self)
        self.confirmed=False
        self.declined=False

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.msg.NoButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(("clicked()")), self.Declined)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.msg.YesButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(("clicked()")), self.Confirmed)

    def Confirmed(self):
        self.confirmed = True
        MessageBox.close(self)
        return True

    def Declined(self):
        self.declined = True
        MessageBox.close(self)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    msg = MessageBox()
    print('Befor show window',msg.confirmed)
    msg.show()
    print('After show window', msg.confirmed)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example doesn't work, because you are printing "After show window" *before* the window has closed. It is the `exec()` method that blocks, not the `show()` method, so your example would need to be written like this:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
msg = MessageBox()
print('Before show window', msg.confirmed)
msg.show()
app.exec_() # this blocks, waiting for close
print('After show window', msg.confirmed)
sys.exit()
```

However, a much more realistic example showing how to use a dialog to confirm an action would be something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MessageBox(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MessageBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.yesButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Yes')
        self.noButton = QtGui.QPushButton('No')
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Are you sure?'), 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.yesButton, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.noButton, 1, 1)
        self.yesButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.noButton.clicked.connect(self.reject)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Do Something')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.confirmSomething():
            print('Yes')
        else:
            print('No')

    def confirmSomething(self):
        msg = MessageBox(self)
        result = msg.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted
        msg.deleteLater()
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```